# Internal and External Authentication against Active Directory users using Asp.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, active-directory, azure-active-directory

I have to create a new ASP.Net MVC web app. This web app will accessed by company users internally and externally. Users are already in active directory.

When accessed externally, authenticate using their AD username and password from login page.

Any reference would be helpful.

Comment: Refer to this GitHub sample for reference - https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-wsfederation

Comment: Also help with exact error you are facing while implementation to better help you

Comment: What if enterprise/company active directory not as Azure AD. Is there alternative without Azure AD?

Comment: I think [Azure AD B2B](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-b2b-what-is-azure-ad-b2b) may be helpful to you.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use Windows authentication when creating the ASP.NET MVC site.

[image: Select Windows authentication]

This requires your web server to be in the same AD as the users, so if you plan to have it hosted somewhere, that is not an option.

If you plan to have the server hosted somewhere outside your AD, you should take a look at ADFS or sync to Azure AD (you don't have to use Azure for anything else).

The built-in authentication methods are described in the [Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/visual-studio/overview/2013/creating-web-projects-in-visual-studio#auth)